# Swift 3 pdf file download not working

Tags: swift, download, swift3

I have a url like this:

```
http://*****.ru/cgi-bin/****/****/cgi.exe?LNG=&C21COM=2&I21DBN=EKU_XML&P21DBN=EKU&Z21ID=1482179537193C7C43181117E030&Image_file_name=%5CFULL%5FTEXT%5CELBIB%5CNarodnye%5Fprazdniki%2Epdf&IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD=1&SECUR=LOG&RIGHT=ALL
```

this url for downloading  *.PDF file.

I use this function for download file

```
//method to be called to download
func download(url: URL)
{
    self.url = url
    //download identifier can be customized. I used the "ulr.absoluteString"
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: url.absoluteString)
    let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig,     delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.downloadTask(with: url)
    task.resume()
}
```

After calling this function, I get cgi.exe file, not pdf file. Why it's happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your URL I can assume, that you are starting your cgi.exe with parameters to generate your pdf file. I think, that you need to send a request to your cgi.exe to generate file and place in response proper link to generated .pdf file. And then start your downloading operations with this URL.

Hope it helps